# JavaFX TableView и огромная таблица

Tags: javafx, tableview

Добрый день. Подскажите пожалуйста. Есть огромная таблица на 10 000 000 записей или больше. Как мне сделать ее вывод групами по 500 000 и чтобы остальная часть подгружалась последовательно. Связано это с тем что при выводе сразу всех записей очень долго думает программа. В какую сторону копать? Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Саму реализацию не подскажу, но идеи могут быть следующие.

1. Можно сначала проставить первые N записей, потом через [Platform.runLater()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-) подгружать остальные записи ( не оптимально, т.к. подгружаться записи будет без необходимости).
2. Можно подписаться на события `scroll` ( [scrollFinish](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setOnScrollFinished-javafx.event.EventHandler-), например), и внутри обработчика смотреть, стоит ли подгружать новые записи. Если стоит, то так же через Platform.runLater() подгружать записи.
3. Переопределить свой кастомный скин для TableView ( должен наследоваться от [TableViewSkin](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/control/skin/TableViewSkin.html)), в котором забрать поле класса flow ( инстанс класса [VirtualFlow](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/control/skin/VirtualFlow.html)), у него забрать индекс последней видимой строки ( `flow.getFirstVisibleCell().getIndex()`)  и смотреть, если эта строка последняя в таблице ( индекс последней видимой строки равен размеру таблицы -1), то тогда так же подгружать следующие строки.